# Show tags in post? Function not working

Tags: tags

I'm using the first example from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags but nothing is showing up.

There's nothing about get_the_tags in my function.php... nor do I know what to put there (sorry, amateur to wordpress)

Just trying to show the tags associated with the post.

Could anyone help?

Comment: where in your template have you put the code? is it within [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Comment: i'm using the twentyeleven theme just modified. it's in the content.php, which is in the loop via index.php, so yes.

Comment: Post the code that you're using, it will make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

```
global $post;
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) 
            {
            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $tagu = $tag->name;
            echo $tagu
                }
            }
```